# Creating a DLL file of C program on ubuntu

Tags: c, dll, cross-platform, ubuntu-16.04

I am able to create .so file of my C program which works fine on ubuntu but I also want this to be worked on windows, so want to **create a DLL file on ubuntu** which can be used on windows, my c program contains a JNI code, how can I create a DLL ? I am using **ubuntu 16.04** (64 bit).